# How to force Android Studio to start with the welcome screen?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, settings, startup, jetbrains-ide

is it possible to let Android Studio start into the welcome screen instead of directly loading the last recent project?

I´ve not really the fastest pc and I often need to switch between projects, its really annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Go to

(as of July 25, 2015)
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Un-check "Reopen last project on startup" -> Click apply

(old version)
File -> Settings -> General -> Startup/shutdown -> Reopen last project on startup.

Un-Check the checkbox.

Or, on the Mac, Preferences -> General -> ....

Comment: even when its loading the project , Clicking on the cancel button will also open the welcome screen .

Comment: @pyus13: With the latest version, when i navigate to File -> Settings, then there is no General Tab.

Comment: @pyus13: I had to close the project and then it took me to Welcome Screen by default.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari they have moved the option to File-->Settings-->Appearance & Behavior-->System Settings--> clear check box for Reopen last project on startup.

Comment: One of the most irritating things in the universe right now, right up there with the fact that quantum physics is confusing, is the fact that Android Studio doesn't have a menu option simply titled  "SHOW THE DAMN WELCOME SCREEN."

Comment: Now you can open welcome screen to manage projects in Android Studio anytime you want:  File -> Open Recent -> Manage Projects... (last item)

Answer (score 12):

It is now not under File, but in the main menu, goto:
Android Studio -> **Preferences** -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> Click on: **System Settings** -> Then you see: **Un-check "Reopen last project on startup"** -> Click apply

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users, as of **Version 4.1.2**, the path is **Preferences** (`CMD + ,`) -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> **System Settings** -> uncheck **Reopen last project on startup**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a screen of a previous projects:
Customize->All settings-> Appearance & Behaviour--> System Settings --> uncheck Reopen projects on startup(under Project section)

Click Apply

Done)