# How do you open a downloaded entire project on android studio including all the parts (src, res, assets, bin, gen, libs, res, settings, manifest)?

Tags: java, android

I recently downloaded the file on this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/gridview/android-gridview-example/ 
Its an android project but I am not sure how to open the entire project and work on it. Is there a way to open the whole thing without having to open each part seperately? I tried to import also but I cant find its destination on the import window on android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the zip you just downloaded and import that folder :

File > New > Import Project

On Android-Studio, If you can't find the destination on the import window, create a folder in your workspace and manually set the destination to that folder on the import window. 
And if you can't find the folder you just created in the "Choose destination directory" dialog window, click the refresh button in the dialog's toolbar

Comment: Easy to do when you're starting up with the "Welcome to Android" screen, with a list of options - Import, Open, Import Eclipse Project etc...See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181847/how-to-force-android-studio-to-start-with-the-welcome-screen on how to get to that screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `Import existing project` in your IDE. I checked the rar file and it is possible that way.

Comment: when i choose import project, i cant find this project. how do i find it or which files exactly do i look for because the project has so many files. im very confused

Comment: You can just import the whole folder. Also you should use Android Studio if you are not already.

Comment: I tried importing the entire project, but when i open the import a project window, it doesnt even show me that folder.

Comment: That is a common bug. You can paste the path to your folder manually.