# how to create a new project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to the android studio and it is the first time that I am using it. But when I create a new project, it doesn't show me the window that I have seen in most videos and I don't know what to do.

Picture of create a project window
[image: Picture of create a project window]

this is what I get, can anyone please help me what to do? I'm stuck.

Comment: It look like you are in Intellij's project wizard instead of the Android studio wizard. Android studio should start up and look like https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/images/studio-welcome_2x.png Then selecting new android studio project will take you through the wizard. If not check the settings and change File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Un-check "Reopen last project on startup" to force it to go to the welcome screen.https://stackoverflow.com/a/21181965/1698182 then https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project

Comment: thanks for the help but it didn't work, still showing the same window

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to already be inside an Android Studio project named: `Project`. On the left of the screen you should see a Project tab with the Android Studio icon, click it to view the structure of your project. That is where you will find the bulk of your application: `src files`, `layout files`, `gradle files`, `manifest`, etc..

This is a great moment for you follow this checklist and take action when necessary:

1. Make sure you have the Java JDK installed. Open a terminal or command-prompt and type `java -version`, and `javac -version`, which will check your Java JRE and Java compiler version respectively. If you don't have them installed you can head over to [Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and download them
2. Once you have JRE and the Java compiler installed, make sure you properly installed Android Studio. There is extensive documentation to help you get started. Follow this guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/install
3. Since you are a complete beginner, I recommend following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/), once you have installed Android Studio correctly. The installation is relatively straightforward, and assuming you used the default configuration during the installation, you should be good to go.

Everything looks normal to me, you just need to familiarize yourself with the IDE itself, so take a look at the links I've attached and I wish you the best!

Comment: I created the project with the window's picture I  have posted in the question but it is not giving me design view or java file, and when I click on the structure, it doesn't show me anything, it's empty. what do I do?

Comment: Did you try creating a new android studio project from the Welcome wizard? Go to **File** > **Close Project**. Then using the smaller window that appears select **Start a new Android Studio Project**

Comment: thanks but I did try it, didn't work. At last, I uninstalled and re-installed the android studio and now it's working fine!